# How to add default to an existing column in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I have this simple table:

```
create table Customers
(
    Id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,
    Name varchar(100) not null,
    IsVip boolean null
)
```

Now I want to set a default value for `IsVip` column. I tried:

```
alter table Customers
modify IsVip set default 0
```

But it doesn't work. How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the ALTER TABLE syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) you use the syntax

```
    | ALTER [COLUMN] col_name SET DEFAULT literal | (expression)
```

or the syntax

```
    | MODIFY [COLUMN] [IF EXISTS] col_name column_definition
```

In your case it can be

```
alter table Customers ALTER COLUMN IsVip set default 0
```

Comment: Yes, I was using `modify` incorrectly. Thank you so much.